# Why is Flutter run taking forever?

Tags: flutter

I run `flutter run` on my Ubuntu 19+ and its taking forever. This is the message am getting below:

> launching lib/main.dart on SM T231 in debug mode... Initializing
>   gradle...

This is taking an unexpectedly long time.

Comment: it does, if its your first launch

Comment: what about dependency?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `flutter run` is taking forever to initialize gradle it is probably due to network problem. Else, you might need to download gradle manually and install it. Downloading gradle manually is advisable especially if you are connected to extremely slow network.

If you can wait enough for gradle to finish downloading the problem should be solved automatically and on the next `flutter run` command it will be significantly faster.

To download gradle manually go to

> [https://gradle.org/install](https://gradle.org/install/)

Comment: Make sure the gradle version matches with the current flutter requirement. Using older versions of gradle might lead to more problems.

Comment: I have installed Gradle manually and put it in the wrapper/dists folder and I have changed the distributionurl in the gradle_wrapper.properties file. And it still takes a long time! Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If it may help, I struggled a lot with `flutter` command on MacOS. `clean`, `run` commands have been taking forever, sometimes they even failed.

In my case, I had `iCloud` syncing the source code directory: **by removing the dir outside of iCloud scope, the problem was gone.**

In my case, the XCode command sticking was `xcrun xcodebuild -list`

Comment: You might have forgot the solution by now.,if you remenber how diy you fix that.I am facing same issue ob ubuntu 22